# ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: ./assets/js/jquery/interview.js
```

I get this error when I try to export a function with module.exports and when I import it inside another file. I tried to use export default but the JS file that calls the original file can't find any method. I also found this topic
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/12731 but I don't have a babel.config.json file...

Here is my code :

```
Interview.prototype = function ($) {
    const collapseLocalStoredElements = function (localStorageId) {
        let collapseItemsIds = localStorage.getItem(localStorageId);
        console.log(collapseItemsIds)
        }
   

    return {
        collapseLocalStoredElements: collapseLocalStoredElements,
    };
}(jQuery);

// export default Interview;
module.exports = Interview;
```

App.js

```
//Import
let InterviewImport = require ('./js/jquery/interview');

//Uses
 let Interview = new InterviewImport();
console.log(Interview.collapseLocalStoredElements('collapseItemsIds'));
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ESM syntax.

```
export default Interview;
```

App.js

```
Import Interview from ('./js/jquery/interview');
```

There also seem to be one too many closing brackets in your code, I've removed the one that I think was unnecessary. The function also seems to be self-executing. You might want to remove that.

```
Interview.prototype = function (localStorageId) {
  let collapseItemsIds = localStorage.getItem(localStorageId);
  console.log(collapseItemsIds);
};
```

Comment: I already tried and app.js  no longer finds the collapseLocalStoredElements method and I get this : "Uncaught ReferenceError: collapseLocalStoredElements is not defined " in the console ...

Comment: Looking at your code, you seem to have a mismatch of brackets. There are one too many closing brackets. I updated my answer regarding this.

Comment: Sorry, I made a copy paste error.. I corrected that but I still have the error.

Comment: Removed the self-executing part of the function. Could you try with the updated code in the answer? Could you also perhaps show how you are using the Interview-object? Might help in debugging.